# How to share widgets between screens

Tags: android, python, kivy, kivy-language

I have a Kivy app with multiple screens, some of which I'd like to share a common widget (a dashboard of sorts). My current implementation simply includes multiple copies of the widget in each screen.

This works fine, but I've noticed that the `on_change` handlers for properties of this widget (of which there are many, since it's updating info regularly) fire once for each screen, even though only one screen is visible at a time. This seems wasteful.

I'd rather not refactor the layout to not use screens (i.e. have a single screen and just switch out the widgets that are not common between screens when "changing"), nor do I want to add `if this_widget_on_current_screen:` style logic to every property's `on_change` handler.

My question is if there's a way to share a single widget instance between multiple screens?

Comment: Could you use a layout with your dashboard  on one side and a `ScreenManager` on the other side?

Comment: I hadn't thought of that, but some screens don't have the dashboard, so I don't think it will work.

Comment: I think you should be able to share a single instance of your dashboard. Just create one instance (and save a reference to it somewhere handy), then  when you want to use it in any `Screen`, you will have to do something like `dashboard.parent.remove_widget(dashboard)`, before doing an `add_widget` to place that same instance in another `Screen`.

Comment: You can probably accomplish the dashboard switching using the `on_leave` and `on_pre_enter` events of a `Screen`.

Comment: Correction. You would have to use `pre_leave` to remove the dashboard (`remove_widget`) from one screen, and `on_enter` to `add_widget` the dashboard to the new `Screen`. Some odd timing going on there.

Comment: Thanks @JohnAnderson. Your idea worked, but I was able to do it by only adding code to the `on_pre_enter` handler of each screen, since the `remove_widget` call can happen anywhere.